# Best approach to port simple javascript game to android

Tags: javascript, android, svg, websocket

I've written simple multiplayer game in javascript. It uses SVG (raphaeljs) and websocekts(websocket.io).

What would be the best approach to port it to android platform?

Would it better to build it from scratch or use phonegap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know of at least one good [WebSocket client library](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/) available for Android (which is used in both of Pusher's Android Java [[1](https://github.com/jmschultz/JavaPusherClient)] [[2](https://github.com/EmoryM/Android_Pusher)]) so the network communication layer shouldn't be a problem.

[This SVG library for android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) looks pretty good.